# Constructors issue

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have to implement a class for representing the books from a library. For each book i have to specify: title, author, ISBN code, year of publication and the price. Then i need to create an array with all the books in a library . This is the code i have worked on and this is the error :

> error C2512: 'Book' : no appropriate default constructor available

What i am doing wrong?

```
    Book.h
      #ifndef BOOK_H
      #define BOOK_H

#include<string>

using namespace std;

class Book
{
private:
    string title;
    string author;
    string code; 
    string edit;
    int year;
    double price;
public:
    Book();
    Book(string t, string a, string c, string e, int y, double p)
    {
        title=t;
        author=a;
        code=c;
        edit=e;
        year=y;
        price=p;
    }
    string GetTitle() const { return title;}
    string GetAuthor() const { return author;}
    string GetCode() const {return code;}
    string GetEdit() const {return code;}
    int GetYear() const {return year;}
    double GetPrice() const {return price;}
};
#endif




Library.h
 #ifndef LIBRARY_H
 #define LIBRARY_H
 #include"Book.h"
 #include<iostream>

 class Library
 {
  private:
    Book books[50];
    int index;
   public:
    Library()
    {
        index=0;
    }
    void Add(Book book)
    {
        books[index]=book;
        index++;
    }
    void PrintAll()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < index; i++)
        {
            Book book=books[i];
            cout<<book.GetTitle()<<":"
    <<book.GetAuthor()<<":"<<book.GetYear()<<endl;
        }
    }
  };
  #endif

   main.cpp


     #include"Library.h"
int main()
{
    Library library;
    Book b1("title1","author1","code1","edit1",1900,34.5);
    library.Add(b1);
    Book b2("title2","author2","code2","edit2",1990,12);
    library.Add(b2);
    library.PrintAll();
}
```

Comment: You can't make an array like that without a default constructor. A vector should do it, though, or an array of `boost::optional`. You also have two semicolons on your `using namespace std`, which probably shouldn't be there in the first place.

Comment: The Library abstraction is wrong. You don't have an array of 50 books when you build a library. A much better library would have a `vector<Book>` where you add books when you create each book (or buy them).

Comment: Two side notes: Your Add method should check for overflow and your PrintAll should stop when it notices an empty title.

Comment: I am a begginer with OOP and i haven't learned yet STL

Comment: @BoPersson: implying you can resize libraries.  If we were following the abstraction perfectly, we'd use an array of book pointers, and set them to null when they get checked out.  Thankfully, we're not following the abstraction perfectly :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now since you have defined a constructor which takes 6 arguments, the compiler won't generate a default constructor for you. So You also need to define a default constructor to support lines of code such as `void Add(Book book) {}`. Maybe something as below:

```
Book() : title(""), author(""), code(""), edit(""), year(1900), price(0.0) 
{}
```

Comment: No, there are no generic books. This is just trying to get around the incorrect abstraction  of a library as a fixed array of books.

Comment: Using an initializer list is better in itself, but strings already default to empty, and it's not clear that 1900 and 0.0 are particularly reasonable values.

Comment: Yeah. I chose them as an example of a default value.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Library` class has an array of `Book` as its member. All members must be initialized at construction. Since you do not call explicitly to `Book` constructor, default one is assumed (in fact for arrays its the only one possible to be called). But no default constructor is present for `Book` hence the compilation error.

Comment: AFAIK C++11 allows to initialize arrays in initialization list.

Comment: That's correct. The code shows the default constructor declared but never defined.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code, you declare an (inline) no-parameter constructor

```
Book();
```

but do not define it, so the compiler cannot find it.

Try eg

```
Book() {};
```

-this just creates an no-parameter constructor that does nothing-, is that's what you meant to do?

Edit - Just seen wnraman reply. That may be more appropriate, as the no-parameter constructor initialises Book to what may be sensible defaults

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have somewhere else in your code a line like

```
Book book;
```

or defined an Array of Books, or used it together with some e-g. List-Classes from a library, which require a default constructor, which is not defined in your class. Either define such a default constructor (which takes no args), or find the offending places in the rest of the code...